# JQuery change text in label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Code:

```
$('#FilesDataTable_length').children()[0];
```

Result: 
http://prntscr.com/895z0y

I need to change "Show " to "Show: ". Can anyone help?

Comment: Please add some more relevant code.. if you can, plese share a fiddle too with us..

Comment: plz show us more code in jsfiddle may be ?

Comment: Based on the screenshot you provided, `#FilesDataTable_length` is a child of `<label>` which is the element containing the _"Show"_ text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a somewhat global solution updating all similar `label`s:

HTML:

```
<label> Show
<select id='111'>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</label><br><br>

<label> Other
<select id='222'>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

JS:

```js
$('label').each( function () {
    var text = $(this).contents().first()[0];
    text.textContent=(text.textContent) + ': '; 
});
```

<kbd>[See Example](https://jsfiddle.net/z8aaqh6v/1/)</kbd>